# C++ Exception in 'nativeRequireModuleConfig', What is Landroid?

Tags: android, react-native

C++ Exception in 'nativeRequireModuleConfig':
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getNoBackupFilesDir(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/io/File; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzx; or its super classes (decleration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzx' appears in /data/app/com.kotac-2/base.apk)
[image: this shows the error]

Comment: It impossible to answer your question without ability to read thoughts on distance.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error you can modify the project into a working state, for example if your project is on git and versioned, reset it into an older commit which it is working well.
I was able to get over this issue by getting the app working however and updating the code again.

Comment: This error occurs after I update Android SDK Manager. Then I roll back to updated packages versions to previous I had. Then error goes.

Comment: @JanakaPushpakumara yes machan.. I did the code rollback to previous git.. it worked. :D thanks btw